# Can we use external pressure in ideal gas equation? And which pressure is used to find enthalpy change?

Tags: thermodynamics

Can we use p as external pressure in ideal gas equation(pv=nrt) ? If not then why is (p delta V = delta n RT) derived using constant external atomspheric pressure? Im a bit confused.

Work done in thermodynamics is calculated using external pressure. In enthalpy change work is used in the formula but im confused as they have derived (p delta v= delta n RT) using constant pressure.

Comment: If the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium then the internal and external pressures must be equal. If the system is undergoing a reversible change then it must be arbitrarily close to a state of thermodynamic equilibrium and so the internal and external pressures can only differ infinitesimally. If the system is undergoing an irreversible change thermodynamics does not deal with it directly and so you must either focus entirely on the end points of the process or use a more involved theory like fluid dynamics

Comment: But sir when we talk about an expansion then the internal pressure wont be equal to external pressure ( talking about irreversible change) so is it possible to still consider the values of external and internal pressure equal at any point of time?

Comment: For a massless piston, the internal pressure of the gas at the inside piston face is always equal to the external pressure at the outside piston face, but, in an irreversible change, the internal pressure for an ideal gas is not described by the ideal gas law.  This is because the gas is not at equilibrium, and the pressure in the gas depends not only on the volume change but also on the rate of change of volume.  In addition, because the gas has mass (inertia), the gas pressure varies with position within the cylinder during an irreversible process.

Comment: However, as @BySymmetry points out, in the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states, the gas does satisfy the ideal gas law.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. I need to learn something from you. Think I asked this once before but let me try again. If I am shown a PV plot as a continuous straight line at a given value of pressure going from some initial volume to a final volume, and involving an ideal gas, I have no way of knowing if the process is reversible or not, is that correct?

Comment: @BobD It depends.  If P is identified as the "external pressure," then you can get the work as the integral of PdV, and it doesn't matter if the process is reversible or not.  But if P is supposed to be the ideal gas pressure (as determined by the ideal gas law), then the process must be reversible (since, for an irreversible process, the pressure may not even be homogeneous, and, in addition, the relation between the volume and the force per unit area on the inside piston face is not described by the ideal gas law).

Comment: @ChesterMiller Got it. Thanks. So, unless we have some way of knowing that the process is a reversible constant pressure process, it may or may not be, but the work will be PΔV either way.

Comment: @BobD Yes, if P is the "external pressure."

Comment: @MunishKatoch So, based on all the comments you have received, are you still confused?